# Error: "The system cannot find the file specified" when using -r flag

Tags: bash, cygwin

Using cygwin bash on Windows XP. Bash version: 4.3.46(7)-release. Minimal working example, sorting an array in reversed order:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=("a c" b f "3 5")
IFS=$'\r\n' sorted=($(sort -r <<<"${array[*]}"))
printf "[%s]\n" "${sorted[@]}"
```

Error in cygwin:

```
-rThe system cannot find the file specified.
```

On Linux works fine. The error is caused by `-r` flag. How to fix?

Comment: The error message looks oddly formatted. Check your script file does not have DOS-style CRLF line endings.

Comment: Do you get the same error for `sort -r <<<a`?

Comment: @Socowi What do you mean? Can post a line of code?

Comment: @user4035 I wanted you to execute the command `sort -r <<<a` (yes, literally just that one line) and post the output/error here.

Comment: @Socowi The output is: "-rThe system cannot find the file specified."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your version of `sort` does not support the `-r` flag. You could ...

- search in `man sort` for an equivalent option.
- Sort normally and reverse the sorted output using another command, for instance `tac` (the reverse of `cat`), or if that isn't available `perl -e 'print reverse <>'`.
  **Example:** Instead of `sort -r <<< "string"` use `sort <<< "string" | tac`.

Please also have a look at [Glenn Jackman's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55033527/6770384) regarding possible problems in your script.

Comment: Yup, this was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think messing with IFS like that will give you the results you seek. Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=("a c" b f "3 5")
readarray -t sorted < <(printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | sort -r)
printf "[%s]\n" "${sorted[@]}"
```

Which outputs

```
[f]
[b]
[a c]
[3 5]
```

---

I think your difficulty lies in here:

```
IFS=$'\r\n' sorted=($(sort -r <<<"${array[*]}"))
```

Referring to [Simple Command Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion), bash does this:

1. it parses the command and sees `IFS=something` and `sorted=something`, tags those as as variable assignments, takes them out of the command line
2. then finds nothing else there to execute as a command,
3. then, left to right, assigns those variables in the current shell

   1. IFS is set to `$'\r\n`
   2. while processing the sorted assignment, bash performs its expansions:
   3. the command substitution is executed:

      1. `"${array[*]}"` is expanded into the string `a c\rb\rf\r3 5` because the `[*]` parameter expansion joins the array elements using the *first character* of $IFS.
      2. `sort -r <<<$'a c\rb\rf\r3 5'`, since it's given one line of input, returns the input unchanged.
   4. now we have `sorted=($'a c\rb\rf\r3 5')`, and since the command substitution is unquoted, word splitting occurs: the string is split using the characters of IFS as delimiters
   5. so we end up with `sorted=("a c" b f "3 5")` which happens to have the same order as the original array.

---

My comment on the line endings of your script:

When the *script file* has DOS-style CRLF line endings, the first line is seen by bash as

```
array=("a c" b f "3 5")$'\r'
```

That means `array` is **not** an array, but a single value:

```
$ IFS=$' \t\n'  # the default value
$ array=("a c" b f "3 5")$'\r'
$ declare -p array
"eclare -- array="(a c b f 3 5)
# ......^^ _not_ "-a" !
```

Comment: I have Unix style line endings in the file. Your script still gives the same error.

Comment: Does the error go away if you remove -r? Check your sort man page. Also check that you're using the sort program you think you are: `type -à sort`